# Updating Angular component field from Promise.catch() does not update UI

Tags: angular, user-interface, promise, try-catch

I'm fairly new to Angular so maybe I'm missing something important here but the code I am using can be found in a lot of repositories and I'm asking myself what I am doing wrong here.

So I have this login component where I want to use Firebase OAuth for signing in. The OAuth part is working fine. I can sign in with Facebook, Google or by email. The problem comes into the game when there is already a user with this or that email. Here is my facebook login code:

```
onLoginFacebook() {
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
    .catch(error => {
      this.error = error.message;
    });
}
```

When there is already a user with a given email, trying to sign in will cause an error with the message

```
"An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address."
```

As you see, I simply assign this error message to a variable of my component which is declared as:

```
public error: string;
```

In my components template, I'd like to use a span to display the error message (for now, that is good enough for me since I am just starting and plan to implement proper error handling later down the road):

```
<span class="error" *ngIf="error" >{{ error }}</span>
```

**And here is the problem:** After setting the error message in my component, nothing happens. However, if I click on any button or input, the message suddenly appears.

I thought that Angular was automatically taking care of updating the UI once I set the variable and if I set the variable outside of the catch() function, e. g. via setTimeout(()=> this.error = "test", 2000), it works as I would expect it. So what am I missing or doing wrong? :(

Comment: Check `Zone.current.name` and try `zone.run`

Comment: Where is this zone property supposed to come from? Is this a third party library? I'd like to keep my code as clean and simple as possible for now

Comment: @yurzui how is `Zone` relevant to the question?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Angular 2 does change detection by using Zones. Basically every asynchronous action is wrapped in a Zone - Zones have a pretty interesting error handling case (so much that Node is blocking them) - part of that is that abstractions that do their own error handling (like promises/observables) do their own error handling - and Angular isn't using Zones correctly to wrap promises. Lucky for us there is one person who is an expert in both, I'll email him this question.

Comment: Looks like the bug is [in this code](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/326a07fb9095e4a87ff7561cb45fe1d4917c2174/lib/common/promise.ts#L405-L407) in Angular's Zone.js, I'll file an issue.

Comment: @xxtesaxx can you please let us know what browser and what promise library (if any) you're using?

Comment: Yes, so I am using Chrome 61.0.3163.100 in combination with the current "save" angularfire2. To be honest, I have no clue which promise library they are using. :/ I guess its rxjs but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Angular. Angular uses [zones](https://github.com/domenic/zones) in order to implement change detection. Zones basically track async contexts.

The way angular does this polyfill is by patching *every async API* the platform has. For example [here is the code for `Promise`](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/common/promise.ts).

If we look at the code closer, we can tell that if `window.Promise` is set - that `.then` is overridden but `.catch` is not. Your code probably has an assignment to `Promise` somewhere and the code that is supposed to handle that looks like this:

```
if (NativePromise) {
  patchThen(NativePromise);

  // ...
```

While `ZoneAwarePromise` does define a `.catch` we can see that `patchThen` only patches `.then` and *does not* override `.catch`. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/936) for zone.js.

Comment: It has been pointed out in the issue this is actually a ECMAScript spec violation, interesting

Comment: It has been pointed out in the issue this is actually a ECMAScript spec violation, interesting